# Displaying a high resolution .png image with pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am currently trying to develop a computer game with pygame - and I'd like to display a background image for the game (2D-jump-and-run).

However I noticed a significant frame-rate drop when displaying a full-screen background image, above a certain window-size:

```
Windowsize | Time to blit the image | (~ FPS)

1280x720:  0.029s (~32 FPS)
1366x768:  0.031s (~29 FPS)
1600x900:  0.042s (~22 FPS)
1920x1080: 0.062s (~15 FPS)
```

Is there a different, more effective way of blitting the image? I wouldn't want to restrict the game to such small window sizes as 1366x768 and lower...

I tried using an image which was smaller concerning the KB-size, as well as trying to blit 4 images with 1/4 the size to cover the screen, but the times remains the same.

The game runs on the pygame screen, so I can't use any functions of e.g. Tkinter (as they would need a Tkinter surface).

Currently im using the following function of pygame:

```
# Once at the beginning
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth_X, screenHeight_Y))

# Every frame
screen.blit(background_Image, (0,0))
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After you loaded the image, did you call the convert method (`background_Image = background_Image.convert()`)? That should make a difference. [Here's the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert)

Comment: Nope, but I will try it out tomorrow! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Blitting unconverted surfaces really kills the performance. Always, use the `convert` or `convert_alpha` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Ted Klein Bergman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486738)'s comment, using `.convert()` and `.convert_alpha`is a huuuuge performance boost.

```
# From originally:
1920x1080: 0.062s (~15 FPS)
# To:
1920x1080: 0.002s (~140 FPS)
```